# Positioning and Sizing a Flash Element Properly in a Div

Tags: css, flash

Here is the code I'm using for the div in question (which is the 3rd box of the javascript dynamic box):

```
<div class="contentdiv" style="margin:-20px 0 10px -30px;">
<object height="100%" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
<param name="movie" value="images/tri.swf">
<embed src="images/tri.swf" height="100%" align=top cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0"> 
</embed>
</object>
</div>
```

Apparently all this .swf is supposed to do is be a countdown for the numbers in the stopwatch.

I want the .swf graphic to fit the div just like the image in box #5 does.

Right now I can't get it to be either the proper size or the proper alignment. I'm admittedly not a Flash expert, so any clues would be great here.

Also, other stuff on the page is totally broken because this is just the "dev" version of the site where I test stuff out. So hopefully that can all be ignored.

Comment: Take a look at the second parameter in both the `object` and `embed` tags. What is its name, and what do you think it does?

Comment: Ok, so are you saying remove the "cellSpacing" tags since we're not working in a table here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing what you are asking, but all you should need to do is just set a height and width on both the `embed` and `object` tags to be the height and width you want. The following uses a width of 50px and a height of 40px, but remember to omit the `px` when declaring it:

```
<div class="contentdiv" style="margin:-20px 0 10px -30px;">
    <object height="40" width="50">
    <param name="movie" value="images/tri.swf">
    <embed src="images/tri.swf" height="40" width="50" align="top"> 
    </embed>
    </object>
</div>
```

Comment: ah, this might have been my issue - previously I was saying "px" ... css thoughts getting in my way.

Comment: @JWM I also missed the cellspacing and cellpadding. Those need to be removed as well.